# Trying to post form JSON data to google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, post

I am trying to do a post method to google sheet using fetch and append to the Spreadsheet but i cant seem to get it to work..

here is my client side javascript

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 const _formData = {
  name: "test_name"
 }

 const jsonFormData = JSON.stringify(_formData);

 const fetchConfig = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  cache: 'no-cache',
  credentials: 'omit',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  },
  redirect: 'follow',
  body: jsonFormData
 }
 
 const URL = "my_url";
 await fetch(URL, fetchConfig);
}
```

Here is the code in google app script

```
function doPost(e){
  
  const body = e.postData.contents,
        bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body),
        sheetName = "test",
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        ws = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  ws.appendRow([
    bodyJSON.name
  ]);
}
```

I did a test to see if i can get a respond using doGet() and it works. There are no errors in my console.log at the client side so i am assuming the JSON has been passed to the correct URL.
But, my spreadsheet did not update.

in my spreadsheet, i have a column - name.

[image]

Comment: Did you try logging something in your app script? If not, use `Logger.log(<VALUE>)` to log

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt seem to log? i tried both console.log and logger.log. it doesn't appear in view.. not sure what i did wrong.